# Logger Program Cannot Find Symbol

Tags: java, singleton

I'm trying to make a Logger class to log some print statements in a small program. This is the code for the Logger class:

```
    public class Logger {

        private static Logger instance = null;
        public long t0;

        public Logger() {
            t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        public static Logger getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new Logger();
            }
            return instance;
        }   

        public void log(Object originator, String text) {
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long t2 = (t1 - t0) * 1000;
            System.out.println(t2 + " - " + originator.getClass().getName() + " : " + text);

        }

    }
```

And I call it in the other files like:

```
    Logger log = Logger.getInstance();  
    log.log(log, "Initializing Centripetal Force");`
```

But I keep getting a cannot find symbol error for the Logger log object.
Any help with this is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posted code runs fine here. What symbol can't be found in your error message?

Comment: Does the Logger and the code that calls it belong to the same package? Please give more details about the code that calls it. And as Elliott Frisch, it would really help to get the exact error message.